# How to implement an interface and apply different rules to an instantiation of the conrete class?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Given this class and interface:

```
public class Property
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string AgencyCode { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Latitude { get; set; }
    public decimal Longitude { get; set; }
}

public interface IPropertyMatcher
{
    bool IsMatch(Property agencyProperty, Property databaseProperty);
}
```

Say there are three possible variations of `AgencyCode`, all with different match rules:

- `Agency1`: match on `.Name` and `.Address`
- `Agency2`: match on `.Latitude` and `.Longitude`
- `Agency3`: match on `.Name` (in reverse)

How can I implement the `IPropertyMatcher` interface in such a way to determine whether the `agencyProperty` is a match for `databaseProperty`, applying these DIFFERENT rules to determine the match depending on the value that is passed in the `agencyProperty.AgencyCode` property?

Answer (score 1):

First you have to create a class implementing the interface. Then define the `IsMatch` method depending on the type:

```
public class Agent1Evaluator : IPropertyMatcher
{
    public bool IsMatch(Property agencyProperty, Property databaseProperty)
    {
        return agencyProperty.Name == databaseProperty.Name && agencyProperty.Address == databaseProperty.Address;
    }
}
```

I am sure you can figure out the remaining two.

Or something like this:

```
const string Agent1 = "Agent1";

public class AgentEvaluator : IPropertyMatcher
{
    public bool IsMatch(Property agencyProperty, Property databaseProperty)
    {
        switch (agencyProperty.AgentType)
        {
            case Agent1:
                return agencyProperty.Name == databaseProperty.Name && agencyProperty.Address == databaseProperty.Address;
            case Agent2:
                ...
        }
    }
}
```

(You could add this method it as `static` method on `Property` too)

Comment: @PatrickHoffman your first suggestion is kinda towards what I'm aiming for - 3 separate concrete implementations ideally, however I can't work out a nice way of creating that instance without violating the separation of concerns principle (which you appear to have done in your second example).

Comment: @JamesLaw: Do you need more input, or is the second answer sufficient for you? Ideally, you would have three classes, and you can override the `Equals` method to create a custom implementation of `==`.

Comment: I did consider overriding the Equals operator but I feel this solution should be implemented using concrete implementations and maintain separation of concerns. Nothing so far manages this so if you've got any more suggestions it would be appreciated.

Comment: I personally wouldn't mind that the class itselfs decides if it equals something else. Why would you?

Comment: If you had to extend it to a large number of agencies, the logical implementation (and case statement) would be very messy and particularly unmanageable.

Comment: Okay. I assume three separate classes would be better then. Not that much options left.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the composite pattern:

```
public class CompositePropertyMatcher : IPropertyMatcher
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IPropertyMatcher> matchers;

    public CompositePropertyMatcher(IEnumerable<IPropertyMatcher> matchers)
    {
        this.matchers = matchers;
    }

    public bool IsMatch(Property agencyProperty, Property databaseProperty)
    {
        return this.matchers.Any(m => m.IsMatch(agencyProperty, databaseProperty));
    }
}

public class PropertyMatcher1 : IPropertyMatcher
{
    public bool IsMatch(Property agencyProperty, Property databaseProperty)
    {
        return agencyProperty.Name == databaseProperty.Name
            && agencyProperty.Address == databaseProperty.Address;
    }
}

public class PropertyMatcher2 : IPropertyMatcher
{
    public bool IsMatch(Property agencyProperty, Property databaseProperty)
    {
        return agencyProperty.Longitude == databaseProperty.Longitude
            && agencyProperty.Latitude == databaseProperty.Latitude;
    }
}
```

Adding a DI library should remove the need to register new implementations.

Here's an example with [SimpleInjector](https://simpleinjector.org/)

```
[Fact]
public void Container_CompositePropertyManager_CallsAllMatchers()
{
    var container = new Container();
    container.RegisterAll<IPropertyMatcher>(this.GetPropertyMatchers());
    container.Register<IPropertyMatcher, CompositePropertyMatcher>();

    var composite = container.GetInstance<IPropertyMatcher>();

    Assert.True(composite.IsMatch(
        new Property { Name = "a", Address = "b", Latitude = 1m, Longitude = 2m },
        new Property { Name = "a", Address = "b", Latitude = 3m, Longitude = 4m }));
    Assert.True(composite.IsMatch(
        new Property { Name = "a", Address = "b", Longitude = 1m, Latitude = 2m },
        new Property { Name = "c", Address = "d", Longitude = 1m, Latitude = 2m }));
    Assert.False(composite.IsMatch(
        new Property { Name = "a", Address = "b", Longitude = 1m, Latitude = 2m },
        new Property { Name = "c", Address = "d", Longitude = 3m, Latitude = 4m }));
}

private IEnumerable<Type> GetPropertyMatchers()
{
    var result =
        from type in typeof(IPropertyMatcher).Assembly.GetTypes()
        where !type.IsAbstract
        where typeof(IPropertyMatcher).IsAssignableFrom(type)
        where type != typeof(CompositePropertyMatcher)
        select type;

    return result;
}
```

Using this technique you can add new pattern matchers without changing any existing code.